# SwiftUI Xcode 11 beta 7 @Binding for collections is breaking preview

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, xcode11, macos-catalina

This was working until beta 7. It seems that when I want to pass one element in a collection as a binding to another view, the preview gets broken

I followed the release notes where it says *@Binding no longer conforms to collection protocol* [comments are at the bottom](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_beta_7_release_notes)

I have Catalina and xcode in beta 7

Parent:

```swift
struct SimpleStructure {
    var label: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var myVariables = [SimpleStructure(label: "hello")]

    var body: some View {
        ChildView(myVariables: $myVariables)
    }
}
```

Child

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var myVariables: [SimpleStructure]
    var body: some View {
        List(myVariables.indexed(), id: \.1.label) {(index, variable) in
            GrandChildView(myVariable: self.$myVariables[index])
        }
    }
}
```

GrandChild

```swift
struct GrandChildView: View {
    @Binding var myVariable:SimpleStructure
    var body: some View {
        Text(myVariable.label)
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Still an issue with Beta 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed in SwiftUI Beta 10

Answer (score 3):

The release notes have a typo. You need to change:

```swift
var endIndex: Index { base.startIndex }
```

with

```swift
var endIndex: Index { base.endIndex }
```

Comment: Nice catch! The error seems to persist after fixing the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno, is this one solved for you? If not, maybe this helps:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var myVariables: [SimpleStructure]

    var body: some View {
        List(myVariables.indices) { index in
            GrandChildView(myVariable: self.$myVariables[index])
        }
    }
}
```

If solved, either mark the correct answer, or provide a solution here by yourself in case you may have found one in the meantime.

Comment: Still broken using `.indices`